# What do the last four characters in a mongodb date timestamp mean?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've been unable to find any documentation that explains meaning of the last four characters in a mongodb timestamp. I'm using mongoose and have models that contain the following:

```
var mySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    created : {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

The result of `created` will contain something like:

```
2014-07-02T01:37:19.729Z
```

What does `729Z` mean? Is it just a random identifier? I've noticed that each timestamp has a different suffix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`729` is the millisecond portion of the timestamp. 729/1000 of a second.

`Z` is "zero" or Zulu Time, otherwise known as Greenwich Mean Time, which is essentially [Universal Coordinated Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (the same, if you don't care about a second here and there). It indicates the timezone of your timestamp. Keeping timestamps in UTC is the standard and best way to do things - it lets you avoid messy seasonal shifts some locations make.